# get twitter screen name

Tags: php, twitter

i am new to OAuth

i want to know how to use "Twitter OAuth library from Abraham Wiliam" to get user's credential information.such as screen_name.

Answer (score 6):

Download this library https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth You need just *twitteroauth.php* and *OAuth.php* files. Only **twitteroauth.php** to include.

Here's the Twitter sample: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples#php

After declaration of `getConnectionWithAccessToken()` function and `$connection` variable with your valid **app tokens** just try code

```
$user = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
print $user->screen_name;
```

according to this [Twitter REST API Reference](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be authenticated to get public user information: you can just use simple web requests to http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/StephenFry.xml etc. [Documentation here.](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-users%C2%A0show)

Comment: i need to get user name of specific user who authenticate with twitter through my site,i have tokens

Comment: It looks like you want to call this API method with an OAuth-authenticated call: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-account%C2%A0verify_credentials. There's example calls to this in both index.php and test.php in Abraham's OAuth library.

Comment: i don't have ids,i only have a token keys which sent by twitter

Comment: Sure - if you use those tokens to authenticate a request to http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.xml, e.g. `$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');` with that library, you'll get back the user information.